# Ubuntu Update causes "Operating System Not Found" on UEFI system

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

I have an Ubuntu Edge E320, and when I got it, I remember hours of hugs frustration because it was very difficult to get an OS onto it. Eventually, I made to install Ubuntu 12.10. I updated to 13.04 in April - no trouble there.

After the new update to 13.10, the BIOS won't find the OS any more. I just get the message `Operating system not found`. I have re-installed Ubuntu entirely about 3 times now, then install Linux Mint 15, also 2 times, and every time the result is the same.

I have also tried to manually install GRUB, to force it into an UEFI-compliance mode, but no luck there.

The partition table is GDT. I have `/dev/sda1` as `ext2`, `/dev/sda2` as `fat16`, giving it the `uefi_boot` flag. I mounted `/dev/sda1` into `/boot` and `/dev/sda2` to `/boot/efi`. Re-installed grub, `grub-install`, etc etc. I have tried 3 tutorials so far, all with the same result.

I also installed [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the Live System. It didn't get me any UEFI-Options like on the screenshots, but I tried anyway. [Here is the complete output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6275145/).

Long story short, I'm really desparate. I really need this notebook for university, and that'll start in a few hours. Been at this all night.

Comment: Why is it `fat16` and why do you have separate partitions for `/boot` and `/boot/efi`. Is it some kind of requirement for UEFI? I have never used UEFI but I always had one `ext4` for `/boot`

Comment: @khajvah Yes, UEFI requires some extra space on the disk for something I never understood. I had to find that out myself when I first installed an OS, took me ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has incompatible signs of using both a BIOS-mode and an EFI-mode setup, so it's not surprising that it's not booting. I recommend you do the following:

1. Boot a Linux live CD *in EFI mode*. If you don't know how to do this, learn. Unfortunately, it's system-specific, but you must generally select the CD-R or USB flash drive boot medium that's described as being "EFI" or "UEFI" in your firmware's boot manager.
2. Using GParted, make the following changes to `/dev/sda2`:

   - Remove the `bios_grub` flag
   - Set the `boot` flag
   - Create a fresh FAT32 filesystem
3. Re-run the Boot Repair utility.

If that doesn't help, try this:

1. Prepare a [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) CD-R or USB flash drive.
2. Boot the rEFInd medium.
3. Highlight the icon that corresponds to a Linux kernel (with `vmlinuz` in the description), but do *not* hit Enter.
4. Hit F2 or Insert twice. This will open a text-mode line editor.
5. Add `ro root=/dev/sda4` to the kernel options.
6. Hit Enter. Linux should boot.
7. Ensure that `/dev/sda2` is mounted at `/boot/efi`. (It should be if you re-ran Boot Repair in EFI mode earlier.)
8. Install the rEFInd Debian package.

Thereafter, the computer should boot using rEFInd as the boot manager, but you should *not* need to edit the kernel options (steps 3-5 above); just highlight a kernel and hit Enter to boot.

Comment: Refind did not install cleanly, it has all the ubuntu-efis I tried before, but it boots, so I can work from there. Many thanks for this tip.